# configuration of jetty work manager programmatically in standalone Java application with Jersey and Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, jndi, workmanagers

I am developing a standalone Java application with Jersey and Jetty. For efficient thread pooling I want to configure work manager and want to deploy my application as jar. I have created server instance in my main launcher class like

```
Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(port));
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
```

I have found different resources where it says I can configure work manager in config.xml like the following.

```
 <work-manager>
   <name>WM</name>
   <max-threads-constraint>64</max-threads-constraint>
   <min-threads-constraint>3</min-threads-constraint>
   <fairshare>80</fairshare>
</work-manager>
```

However if I want to configure the same thing programmatically in my main class and other resources like JDBC Datasource, how do I do that? Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using jetty version **9.4.16.v20190411** and my pom entry

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Edit: I want to get parameterized work manager like

```
private WorkManager getWorkManager(String workManagerName) throws RuntimeException {

    String workManagerLookupName = null;
    try {
        workManagerLookupName = "java:comp/env/" + workManagerName;
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        //Resource resource = new Resource("java:comp/env/" + workManagerName,);
        WorkManager wm = (WorkManager) ic.lookup(workManagerLookupName);
        return wm;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get WorkManager instance for " + workManagerLookupName, e);
    }
}
```

Is it possible programmatically ??

Answer (score 1):

You can create a threadPool config and pass it to the server constructor:

```java
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
threadPool.setMaxThreads(64);
threadPool.setMinThreads(3);
Server server = new Server(threadPool);
```

Description how to add JDBC Datasource can be found here:
[Jetty Bind DataSource in JNDI Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816627/jetty-bind-datasource-in-jndi-context)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, Unfortunately i assume, Jetty does not provide any implementation class of work manager interface like weblogic server has inbuilt in it..Any idea?